# How to exclude library from specific entry?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have my root app that can import bundles of sub apps. Sub apps can be run in a standalone mode as well. The problem is that root app and imported sub app use different instances of library (probably, the versions of lib instances are the same). I want them use only one copy of library.
So, I want in my webpack config something like that:

```
entry: {
    standalone: 'standalone.js', // bundle for standalone mode
    render: {                    // bundle for sub app
        name: 'render.js',
        exclude: ['react'],
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?